# Oracle UNION different columns

Tags: oracle, ora-00918

I have two tables looking something like:

```
TABLE_1
COL_A (int), COL_B (float), COL_C (float)


TABLE_2
COL_A (int), COL_B (float)
```

My query is using a UNION to put the results of these tables together, but where TABLE_2 doesn't have a COL_C, I'm looking to put something like '0'.
But I just get a **'ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined'** error

How can I get around this?

Comment: Can you post your SQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT COL_A, COL_B, COL_C FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT COL_A, COL_B, 0 As COL_C FROM Table2
```

Comment: Thanks for that, the AS COL sorts it, giving them the same column name.

Comment: This answer is really acceptable. But the other answer  by @jramesh1967 makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COL_A,COL_B,COL_C FROM TABLE_1
UNION
SELECT COL_A,COL_B,'0' AS COL_C FROM TABLE_2
```

You may also be able to get away with

```
SELECT COL_A,COL_B,COL_C FROM TABLE_1
UNION
SELECT COL_A,COL_B,'0' FROM TABLE_2
```

The basic idea is that both must have same number of columns of the same corresponding data types.

Comment: Thanks for that, the AS COL sorts it, giving them the same column name.

Comment: @jramesh1967, `COL_C` is `FLOAT` and **NOT** a string. So why do you have single quotes around the `NUMBER 0`?

Comment: @KPS-UK, why do you jump on conclusion when this answer defeats the purpose to help you? Also there are no code tags applied, such an unprofessional way of answering to a question.

Comment: Why do you get so upset about things that don't affect you? I didn't jump on conclusion, the answer did not defeat it's purpose. 0 AS COL_C resolves my problem. Why didn't you just provide a more 'professional' answer?

Comment: I was just trying to help you to understand that `0 as a number` is not same as `'0' as a literal`. It would only kill the performance as the optimizer would have to go for `implicit conversion`. If you are OK with the answer, I have no issues, but my honest intention is to make you aware of the difference between the two answers posted.